# AssertionError 25 on getExtent, Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, angular

When doing `this.map.getView().fit(this.layer.getSource().getExtent())` with my vector layer I get an assertion error as following:

> AssertionError {code: 25, name: "AssertionError", message: "Assertion
>   failed. See https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.3/doc/errors/#25 for
>   details."} code: 25 message: "Assertion failed. See
>   https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.3/doc/errors/#25 for details." name:
>   "AssertionError"

This is the value received from the server and applied to the vector source:

```
 { 
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "totalFeatures":1,
   "features":[ 
      { 
         "type":"Feature",
         "id":"CATAST_Pol_Municipio.201",
         "geometry":{ 
            "type":"MultiPolygon",
            "coordinates":[ 
                //Long text
            ]
         },
         "geometry_name":"the_geom",
         "properties":{ 
            "FEATURE":200020,
            "CMUNICIPIO":201,
            "MUNICIPIO":"Pamplona / Iruña",
            "MUNINOAC":"Pamplona / Iruña",
            "GEOM_AREA":2.509439497E7,
            "GEOM_PERI":36044.89,
            "BEGINLIFE":"04/10/2019"
         }
      }
   ],
   "crs":{ 
      "type":"name",
      "properties":{ 
         "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25830"
      }
   }
}
```

If I do `this.layer.getSource().getExtent()` I get:

[Infinity, Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity]

> How can I solve this error or get the correct extent with the received
>   values from the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link doesn't work in version 5.3.3 so here is the 5.3.0 version https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/doc/errors/#25

The data is loaded to the source asynchronously so you need to open the view at a arbitrary setting then fit when the data is loaded

```
this.layer.getSource().on('addfeature' (e) => {
  this.map.getView().fit(this.layer.getSource().getExtent());
});
```