# AJAX Request (Point Feature, Format GML) with fetch API from WFS failed

Tags: javascript, openlayers, point, wfs, ajax

I work with OpenLayers 6.9.0. Individual polygon and point features are displayed on the map with a GetFeature request via WFS. The WFS delivers GML, no GeoJSON. Points and polygons come from the same WFS layer.
The WFS is accessed via AJAX using the fetch API and Promises.
The following code is used:

```
  // Send request with POST
  fetch ('https: // localhost: 8443 / deegree-webservices-3.4.3 / services / WFS', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
    body: new XMLSerializer (). serializeToString (featureRequest)
  })
  // Response
    .then (function (response) {
        return response.text ();
     })
  // read the GML feature
    .then (function (text) {
        var feature = new ol.format.GML2 ({
srsName: 'EPSG: 25832'})
.readFeature (text);
      vectorSource.addFeature (feature);
      // Zoom to the extent in the view
map.getView (). fit (this.vectorSource.getExtent (),
{padding: [60, 60, 60, 60]});
});

 var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
      
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
  minZoom: 6,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)',
      width: 3
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)',
   }),
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 140,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)',
      })
    })
  })
});
```

This works great with polygon features. The problem arises when loading point features. Then there is an AssertionError 25.

Until getExtent () the code works with the debugger in the console.
vectorSource contains the point coordinates, but the AssertionError occurs and nothing is visible on the map.

VectorSource:

```
j: {…}
    datum: "2020-09-30"
    erfasser: "TP"
    geom: {…}
        Point: {…}
            gid: "APP_POINT_V_01/1111_APP_GEOM"
            kd: {…}
                coord: {…}
                    X: "469461.418 
                    Y: "5696127.248"
                    srsName: "EPSG:25832"
```

The response from the WFS for polygons is a GML2.1.2 with coordinates as a string:

```
    <gml:Polygon gid="APP_POINT_V_11/11_APP_GEOM" srsName="EPSG:25832">
      <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
        <gml:LinearRing srsName="EPSG:25832">
          <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">long List……</gml:coordinates>
        </gml:LinearRing>
      </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
    </gml:Polygon>
```

However, the response for the point is a GML2.1.2 with coordinates as  elements:

```
    <gml:Point gid="APP_POINT_V_01/1111_APP_GEOM" srsName="EPSG:25832">
      <gml:coord>
        <gml:X>469461.418</gml:X>
        <gml:Y>5696127.248</gml:Y>
      </gml:coord>
    </gml:Point>
```

If I download the GML and change it so that coordinates are given as a string, OpenLayers parses this (for the test GML directly as a file in the URL):

```
    <gml:Point gid="APP_POINT_V_01/1111_APP_GEOM" srsName="EPSG:25832">
        <gml:coordinates>469461.418,5696127.248</gml:coordinates>
    </gml:Point>
```

Is there a trick that OpenLayers also processes the other form of GML2 ?

Comment: The `geom` property you have shown is not an OpenLayers geometry object.  The parser has not recognised it as a GML2 geometry.  As you sure the format to use is GML2?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Polygons and points are fetched from the same data source. With the GetFeature Request I get both points and polygons with the following OpenLayers configuration: version: '1.1.0', outputFormat: 'text / xml; subtype = gml / 2.1.2 ',. Therefore I assumed that both geometry types are also delivered by the WFS server in GML2. This is not the case. <gml: coord> <gml: X> 469461.418 </ gml: X> <gml: Y> 5696127.248 </ gml: Y> </ gml: coord> cannot parse OL 6 as GML2. Unfortunately, I have no influence on the WFS.

Comment: Did you try GML3?

Comment: related? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/341678/assertionerror-25-on-getextent-openlayers